# jQuery draggable helper clone event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to drag items around.  The items have click events.  I'd like to register clicks where the user moves the mouse a little while the button is still down, so, using mouseup instead of click is the obvious answer, but!  I need to use helper: 'clone' on drag, because items are in a container set to overflow: scroll (or auto) and I need to drag(/drop) outside of that container.

So the question is, is there a way to register a mouseup event on the clone?

I'd also need access to the original item - for a colour change, let's say.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kFBtr/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/), something like this:

```
jQuery('body').delegate('.ui-draggable-dragging','mouseup',function(){alert('OMG!! Mouse Up')})
```

To access the original element, just use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
function(){jQuery(this).prev()}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kFBtr/1/